# How to handle such case in promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array where each element will go through 2 nested async tasks if some conditions hold. Otherwise, will go through 1 normal sync task and when all done return the array with the new updates.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
    someFunction(array) {
    array.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (some checks hold) {
        asyncTask1(element).then(updatedElement => {
          asyncTask2(updatedElement).then(elementFinal => {
            array[index] = elementFinal;
          });
        });
        return;
      }
      array[index] = normalSyncTask(element);
    });
  }
```

I need this function to return the updated array only when all elements are processed:

`someFunction(array).then(updatedArray => {
   // Do something with the updated array
 });`

This was my attempt:

```
someFunction(array) {
    var promises = [];
    array.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (some checks hold) {
        var promise = asyncTask1(element);
        promise.then(updatedElement => {
          asyncTask2(updatedElement).then(elementFinal => {
            array[index] = elementFinal;
          });
        });
        promises.push(promise);
        return;
      }
      array[index] = normalSyncTask(element);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => Promise.resolve(array));
  }
```

Excuse my stupid attempt but I cannot really get a good grasp of how promises exactly work no matter how many tutorials I read.

Comment: Is using a library like bluebird an option?

Comment: @t.niese It would be better if it can be done without resorting to external libraries.

Comment: @t.niese how would a library like bb help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
someFunction(array){
    const promises = array.map((element, index) => {
        if(some checks hold){
            return asyncTask1(element).then(asyncTask2);
        }
        return normalSyncTask(element);
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
        console.log('Everything is OK', values);
    });
}
```

You generate an array of promises using `Array.map`and wait for all of them to be resolved using `Promise.all`.

The values that are not a promise will be ignored by `Promise.all` and be returned with the promises results in the `values` array returned by the function.

Comment: Instead of writing `.then(updatedElement => asyncTask2(updatedElement));` you could just write `.then(asyncTask2);`. That way you will directly see, that the result of the promise is passed to the function.

Comment: True, i've updated the code accordingly ;) Code could be improved further using a ternary operator but that would make it more confusing for people that are not familiar with how it works

Comment: Ternary operators most of the time decrease readability. Shorter code does not mean easier to read. It was less about to shorten the code, and more about that for `.then(updatedElement => asyncTask2(updatedElement));` you would need to check if the parameter `updatedElement` is really equal to the argument that is passed to `asyncTask2', and with `.then(asyncTask2` you would immediately see that it is a pass through.

Answer (score 1):

Your was very close with your attempt

```
function someFunction(array) {
    var promises = [];
    array.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (some checks hold) {
            // push Promise from last async function
            promises.push(asyncTask1(element).then(updatedElement => {
                return asyncTask2(updatedElement).then(elementFinal => {
                    array[index] = elementFinal;
                });
            }));
            return;
        }
        array[index] = normalSyncTask(element);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => array);
}
```